# Python 3 os.system output from system shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I pass an argument to the system shell in Python and get the output back as an array or string?

Comment: You should have a look at the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html) module and specially at the [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.system` is not designed to do that; [`os.popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) is. Both have been obsoleted by the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), which should be used for writing new code. To capture the output of a shell command, you would instantiate a `subprocess.Popen` object and call `communicate()` to retrieve its output.

In addition to the above, [the utility function `check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), new in Python 2.7, is a plugin-replacement for shell backquotes, i.e. you pass it the command to execute and get back the output as a string:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-a'])
'.\n..\n'
```